# Provide schema while reading avro files using pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, schema, avro

I am trying to read avro files using pyspark. I want to provide my own schema while reading the file. Below is the sample code.

```
json_schema = """
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "User",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "routingNumber",
            "type": "string"
        }
        
    ]
}
"""

schema_dict = json.loads(json_schema)
avro_schema = StructType.fromJson(schema_dict)

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("AvroReadExample")\
        .config('spark.jars', '/Users/harbeerkadian/Documents/workspace/learn-spark/jars/spark-avro_2.12-3.5.0.jar')\
        .getOrCreate()
    df = spark.read.format("avro").schema(avro_schema).load("/Users/harbeerkadian/Downloads/accounts.avro")
```

It is giving errors where I am tyring to convert the schema json into StructType.

Below is the error details

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/harbeerkadian/Documents/workspace/learn-python/solution.py", line 992, in <module>
    avro_using_files()
  File "/Users/harbeerkadian/Documents/workspace/learn-python/solution.py", line 954, in avro_using_files
    avro_schema = StructType.fromJson(schema_dict)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/harbeerkadian/Documents/workspace/python_env/ncr-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1017, in fromJson
    return StructType([StructField.fromJson(f) for f in json["fields"]])
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/harbeerkadian/Documents/workspace/python_env/ncr-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1017, in <listcomp>
    return StructType([StructField.fromJson(f) for f in json["fields"]])
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/harbeerkadian/Documents/workspace/python_env/ncr-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 709, in fromJson
    json["nullable"],
    ~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'nullable'
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be with the `json_schema` variable that you have defined. When you invoke the `StructType.fromJson` method you need to pass some compulsory keys, since you're variable `json_schema` is missing them you are getting the `KeyError`.

In general, when you define the schema as a json that is going to be used as an input to the `StructType.fromJson` method, you can use the below structure:

```json
[
    {
        "name": "fieldName1",
        "type": "string",
        "nullable": true,
        "metadata": {}
    },
    {
        "name": "fieldName2",
        "type": "integer",
        "nullable": false,
        "metadata": {}
    }
    // Add more field definitions as needed
]
```

In Avro schema, The `StructType` only cares about the `fields` array, where each field is converted into a `StructField`. Each `StructField` requires a `name`, `type`, `nullable`, and `metadata` key.

So the `json_schema` variable must look like this:

```py
json_schema = """
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "User",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "routingNumber",
            "type": "string",
            "nullable": true,
            "metadata": {}
        }
    ]
}
"""
```

I have assumed the `routingNumber` column can have null values hence `nullable: true`, please change it if otherwise. It should work fine after this change.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to load avro file with provided schema.

```
import json
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

account_schema = {
    "type": "record",
    "name": "Account",
    "namespace": "com.ncr.banking.niis.model",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "accountFeature",
            "type": [
                "null",
                {
                    "type": "record",
                    "name": "AccountFeature",
                    "fields": [
                        {
                            "name": "billPayEnabled",
                            "type": ["null", "boolean"]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

spark = SparkSession.builder. \
    config('spark.jars',
           '/Users/harbeerkadian/Documents/workspace/learn-spark/jars/spark-avro_2.12-3.5.0.jar').getOrCreate()

avroDF_read = spark.read.format("avro").option("avroSchema", json.dumps(account_schema)) \
    .load("/Users/harbeerkadian/Documents/temp/work/txnstore_accounts_new.avro")


print(avroDF_read.schema)
print(avroDF_read.show())
```

use json.dumps method only when converting account_schema dict into string. Using str method changes double quotes into single quotes and then it does not works.